# external content load causes div not to extend to bottom of page

Tags: jquery, html, css

Here's the css:

```
.container{
    background-image:url('images/containerbg.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    width:1078px;
    background-color: #000;
    margin:0 auto 0 auto;
    position:relative;
}
```

Here's a pic of what is happening:

[image]

Comment: 100% height has no meaning unless all of the element's parents also have 100% height.

Comment: the container here is the black div

Comment: What is the container in? Its height is 100% of its parent's height. If you just want the height to be dynamic based on content, don't set a height

Comment: The .container is the first div under <body>. I removed the height prop and have same result.

Comment: I should say html and body css have no height set too

Comment: Please provide more code. What is `images/containerbg.png` supposed to look like? If it's a black rectangle, then everything's behaving normally.

Comment: the png is a 1078x956 image.. the black background color should extend with content tho right? I found this is happening even without adding external content with jquery. Using lastest FF and IE browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `overflow: hidden`:

```
.container {
    overflow: hidden; // or overflow: auto;
    ....
}
```

Comment: that works, but the content gets cutoff and I can't scroll down. :(

Comment: @Inserter try removing the height property.

Comment: that works but puts a scrollbar on the black .container div. I tried overflow:auto for both html and body individually and no luck there either